# use android 6.0 api 23 permissions to low devices(like api 22 almost)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-library

it's my first question here and maybe i'll explain a little bad, but okay look:
I have a project with its using api 22 library, but compiles with android 6.0(api 23), and i wanna continue with api 22 library, but when i run my project with android 6.0 device i have problems with the permissions...

My question: is there a way that you can work in, for example, Android 5.1.1 and compile with Android 6.0 with the necessary permission's methods? i mean, can i add some library, for use callback like `onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` ? i tried adding api 23 library to my project but isnt works his methods, any suggestion...??

Comment: this will be help full for u http://www.sathyabaman.com/2016/06/19/permissions-in-android-6-0-api-level-23/

Comment: i have readed something like that before, but i just want to know if i can continue working with api 22 or it's necessary change all my project to api 23? or is there a way to solution my problem...

Comment: There is no issues in working with API 22 or 23. If you don't request the permission as mentioned, it will work with all the devices that is running android 5 and below. but when you run it on Android 6.0 the app will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.　Checkout if the permission you need is a dangerous permission at [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).
2.　List all dangerous permissions you need in a `String` array like below.

```
private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{your_permissions_here};
```

3.　Add the following code to your onCreate().

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    LinkedList<String> missingPermissions = new LinkedList<>();
    for(String p : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
        if(checkSelfPermission(p) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            missingPermissions.add(p);
        }
    }
    if(!missingPermissions.isEmpty()){
        String[] mpArray = new String[missingPermissions.size()];
        missingPermissions.toArray(mpArray);
        requestPermissions(mpArray, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}
```

`REQUEST_PERMISSIONS` is a constant integer to identify this requesting.

Comment: I understand, but when i add the method `requestPermissions(...)` is giving me an error, its shows that "its undefined for the type myClass.java" and calling `Build.VERSION_CODES.M` (M isnt found)...i think i need to add somewhere a marshmallow's library...right? cause im working at api 22 library...or anoter solution for your answer?